# How do I access a .docx file from my assets folder?

Tags: android, kotlin, apache-poi

I have this code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
....
        val am = assets as AssetManager
        val strang = am.open("report.docx").toString()
....
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{android.report/android.report.MainActivity}: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: report.docx
```

I created a new folder in res called assets and dropped it off there, but it's still not finding it. Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I created a new folder in res called assets and dropped it off there

That is not where `assets/` goes. It belongs as a subdirectory of your source set (e.g., `main/`). In other words, it is a *peer* of `res/`, not a subdirectory of `res/`.

```
val strang = am.open("report.docx").toString()
```

Since AFAIK DOCX files are [binary files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), I suspect that this will not work well.